# Representation of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ given by $t \rightarrow A(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & t\\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$ does not have an invariant inner product

Tags: representation-theory

The question is as it is from the title; let $A(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and let $\pi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C}^{2})$ be a representation of the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi: t \rightarrow A(t)$, and I want to show that such representation does not have an invariant inner product.

First of all, it seems like I could not find an appropriat definition of invariant inner product for the context of this question (from exhaustive googling, I found different definitions for invariant inner products but not sure which one is correct from the context of this question), and due to that, I got stuck at this question for a while. Could anyone provide a definition of invariant inner product and insight to this problem? Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: If $V$ is a representation of $G$, an inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$ on $V$ is invariant if $(g \cdot v, g \cdot w) = (v, w)$ for all $g \in G$ and all $v,w \in V$. In other words, the action of $G$ is unitary. So the keyword you want to look up is unitary representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An invariant inner product is a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $(,)\colon\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2\to \mathbb C$ such that $(\pi(t)v,\pi(t)w)=(v,w)$ (sometimes it is required to be anti-linear in the second variable but the proof is the same).

Suppose such an inner product exists. Then $\pi(t)e_1=e_1$ for any $t\in\mathbb R$, so
$$(e_1,e_2)=(\pi(1)e_1,\pi(1)e_2)=(e_1,e_1+e_2),$$
i.e., $(e_1,e_1)=0$. Moreover,
$$\begin{align*}(e_2,e_2)&=(\pi(1)e_2,\pi(1)e_2)\\&=(e_1+e_2,e_1+e_2)\\&=(e_1,e_1)+2(e_1,e_2)+(e_2,e_2)\\
&=2(e_1,e_2)+(e_2,e_2),\end{align*}$$
i.e., $(e_1,e_2)=0$. Thus for any $v\in \mathbb C^2$ we have $(e_1,v)=0$, which contradicts the bilinear form being non-degenerate.

---

Note: If the symmetric requirement is dropped, $(ae_1+be_2,ce_1+de_2)=ad-bc$ is a counter-example.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much for your help!